# What does the hyp checkbox do on calculators?

Tags: calculator

What does the hyp checkbox do on calculators (for example on the Microsoft Windows calculator)?

Comment: Is there a "help" feature on that calculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used to select hyperbolic functions (i.e. hyperbolic sine, cosine).

Comment: sin becomes sinh and so on.  If you haven't heard of hyperbolic functions, and you haven't studied calculus yet, then just wait to find out about it.  If you *have* studied calculus, but your instructor skipped that material, then you are the loser because of it: you my have to pick it up in engineering or physics courses, or other math courses which assume you know it.